# Infinite redirect loop to https

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

I added this simple piece of middleware to my asp.net core web app according to this post: [Redirect to HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29477393/asp-net-core-redirect-to-https)

```
if (!env.IsLocalhost())
{
            app.Use(async (context, next) =>
            {
                if (context.Request.IsHttps)
                {
                    await next();
                }
                else
                {
                    var withHttps = "https://" + context.Request.Host + context.Request.Path;
                    context.Response.Redirect(withHttps);
                }
            });
            app.UseMiddleware<RedirectHttpMiddleware>();
}
```

After deploying to Azure I have an infinite redirect loop.

I have verified that the middleware is causing the infinite loop (if I comment it out the loop goes away) and that IsHttps is indeed true.

Does anybody have a suggestion as to why this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this for RC1 using this block of code:

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
            {
                String protoHeader = context.Request.Headers["X-Forwarded-Proto"];
                if (protoHeader.ToLower().Equals("https"))
                {
                    await next();
                }
                else
                {
                    var withHttps = "https://" + context.Request.Host + context.Request.Path;
                    context.Response.Redirect(withHttps);
                }
            });
```

Comment: `app.UseIISIntegration()` should do this for you in RC1.

Comment: Ok I appreciate the hint. Will try it out next time I have the chance to improve.

Answer (score 4):

This is a known issue when running in azure. https://github.com/aspnet/IISIntegration/issues/140

You can workaround it by adding the following in ConfigureSerivces:

```
        services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
        {
          options.ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
        });
```

Comment: I can confirm, this does fix the problem. Important to note that this issue has been fixed in RTM expected June 27th, 2016.

Comment: @Tratcher Even though I believe this is the right answer I still cannot validate it because the code shown above is based on RC2 and we are using RC1. Can anyone suggest what to do when working with RC1?

Comment: RC1 was not affected by https://github.com/aspnet/IISIntegration/issues/140. Do you have `app.UseIISIntegration()` in your pipeline ahead of your redirect middleware? This was required for RC1 but is not needed for RC2.

Comment: @Tratcher Well, the above code does not compile at all. It seems to me that the classes implied (such as ForwardedHeadersOptions) are only available in the the RC2 assemblies. I added 
    "Microsoft.AspNet.HttpOverrides": "1.0.0-rc1-final" to project.json but even with this the ForwardedHeadersOptions cannot be resolved. Anyway, I managed to solve it using some simpler block of code, cf. the answer posted by myself.