# ASP.NET Core Reverse Proxy and IdentityOptions Paths

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, reverse-proxy

I am running my Kestrel servers behind an IIS Reverse Proxy (.NET Core 1.0.0). It works great, except, certain cases - such as being redirected to a login page upon failed access - results in the user being sent to `http://localhost:8080/Account/Login` (the address that Kestrel is bound to) instead of `http://www.example.net/Account/Login` (the reverse proxy address).

I know that I can configure IdentityOptions in `Startup.cs`, which also includes the ability to set LoginPath, like:

```
services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
{
    options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
    options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.SlidingExpiration = true;
    options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.LoginPath = PathString("/Admin/Login");
});
```

Unfortunately, I cannot set an absolute path.

I also looked into the possibility to inspect and rewrite the URL per [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29477556/132528), but I feel like this may not be the right way to go, though I don't have any direct reason as to why.

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    var baseUri = Configuration["Site:BaseUri"];
    if (baseUri.Contains(context.Request.Host.ToString()))
    {
        await next();
    }
    else
    {
        var newUri = $"{context.Request.Scheme}://{baseUri}{context.Request.Pat‌​h}{context.Request.Q‌​ueryString}";
        context.Response.Redirect(newUri);
    }
});
```

On top of all of this, I did find [this link from the FunnelWeb project](https://bitbucket.org/TheBlueSky/funnelweb/src/b64c74f361d3701526b4b2488aed30a0df4a6120/src/FunnelWeb/Utilities/HttpRequestExtensions.cs?fileviewer=file-view-default) which basically looks like what I am wanting to do (although, for an older version of ASP.NET).

I would appreciate any guidance to point me in the right direction.

Comment: How you tested that it is not redirected to example.net ? Means How you hosted site ? Local IIS or some other way.

Comment: How do you setup port in your Startup.cs file? Do you use the IIS integration option?