# ASP.Net Core: Where to put app.Use() call to force HTTPS

Tags: ssl, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I've tried a lot of different things and I'm just tired of banging my head on my desk.

I'm creating an ASP.NET Core MVC website.  The site works fine until I start trying to test functionality in SSL.  I've tried the following links:

- [ASP.Net Core Enforcing HTTPS (Longing To Know)](https://long2know.com/2016/07/asp-net-core-enforcing-https/)
- [Testing SSL in ASP.NET Core (Wildermuth's Blog)](https://wildermuth.com/2016/10/26/Testing-SSL-in-ASP-NET-Core)
- [Redirect to HTTPS (StackOverflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29477393/redirect-to-https)

The third item kept reappearing on a number of other links, so I attempted multiple ways to get that working.  I've moved the code setup into several locations of the Startup class' `Configure` method.  If I place the code segment anywhere before the `app.UseMvc()` call, I get absolutely nothing:  the home page (which isn't under SSL) doesn't come up so I can't follow any links.  When I place it after the `app.UseMvc()` call, any method that uses the `[RequireHttps]` attribute goes to the "doesn't exist" link.  That makes some sense, since I want to use MVC.  But how can I test HTTPS?

Where does the code for `app.Use(async (context,next)...` go?

My current `Startup.cs`:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
    loggerFactory.AddDebug();
            var sslPort = Configuration.GetValue<int>("iisSetting:iisExpress:sslPort");

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseBrowserLink();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    }

    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });

    app.Use(async (context, next) =>
    {
        if (context.Request.IsHttps)
            await next();
        else
        {
            var sslPortStr = ((sslPort == 0) || (sslPort == 443)) ? string.Empty : ($":{sslPort}");
            var sslUrl = $"https://{context.Request.Host.Host}{sslPort}{context.Request.Path}";
            context.Response.Redirect(sslUrl);
        }
    }); // */
}
```

**UPDATE:** (2017/01/26)
I've discovered that if I manually enter the SSL port number into the browser URL, the system enters SSL/HTTPS...but then it stays there, even on the pages that don't need security.

What I'm trying to do is have the correct port numbers show up in the URL without manually needing to type them...and only for testing purposes.

Answer (score 0):

you do it in configure services:

```
services.Configure<MvcOptions>(options =>
{
    options.Filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute());
});
```

however that will fail (404) if there is no ssl certificate. [running directly from kestrel](https://wildermuth.com/2016/10/26/Testing-SSL-in-ASP-NET-Core) would be different than with IIS Express. With VS 2015 you can check the box in the project properties to use ssl and it will generate a self signed cert for you automatically for IIS Express

Comment: As stated above, trying this gives HTTP 404 on the home page.  I did check the box in properties for the project, which is where I have the HTTPS port from.  I also would prefer not to use Kestrel any further than it's already in the project if I can avoid it.  I actually did follow the link you provided before posting, but I'm not getting the results Wildermuth implies.

Comment: As long as you run it in IISExpress the self signed cert should work. You do need to change the launch url to match the ssl url generated when you tick that box. The non-ssl url will give a 404 once you apply the filter so if you are still using that as the launch url that could be the problem

Answer (score 0):

You could do what you are doing before `app.UseStaticFiles();`. Then any calls for files or MVC routes will be redirected to the secure version.

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    if (context.Request.IsHttps)
        await next();
    else
    {
        var sslPortStr = ((sslPort == 0) || (sslPort == 443)) ? string.Empty : ($":{sslPort}");
        var sslUrl = $"https://{context.Request.Host.Host}{sslPort}{context.Request.Path}";
        context.Response.Redirect(sslUrl);
    }
});
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

I just wrote a small article on this as well: https://joonasw.net/view/enforcing-https-in-aspnet-core.

Comment: When I do this, I get HTTP 404.

Comment: Sorry.  For some reason, I can't edit the previous post.  I get the HTTP 404 on the home page when I move the app.Use call anywhere before the app.UseMvc call. I did find either your link or a similar link that talked about creating a middleware.  My issue with that is that I'm only trying to test at the moment.  By all accounts, if I publish the site, the HTTPS will work given a valid certificate.  Is there a way to add HTTPS solely for testing purposes?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure it when you add mvc.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc(options =>
    {
        options.SslPort = 433; // your ssl port no
        options.Filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute());
    });
}
```

Comment: This also gives HTTP 404 on the home page.